# Word problem related to ratios and proportions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem, ratio

This is the problem at hand:

> Farmer John has 41 hens. If he had one more solid colored hen, then exactly one-third of his hens would be speckled.
>   From years of experience, Farmer John knows that one-half of the speckled hens will lay speckled eggs and that each hen
>   and a half will lay an egg and a half in a day and a half. After how many full days will Farmer John have 11 dozen
>   speckled eggs to sell?
>   Explain your reasoning

I am able to do this problem when I add one more hen so Farmer John has 42 hens.  However, he only has 41 and I am just not sure how to go about figuring out this problem.  If he had 42 colored hens then exactly 1/3 of them are speckled.  He only has 41 though?

Comment: So how many speckled hens would he have if he had $42$ in total? How many speckled hens does he have?

Comment: If a hen and a half will lay an egg and a half in a day and a half, then how many eggs will one hen lay in a day and a half?

Comment: If he had 42 in total then he would have 14 hens.  7 of those hens would lay speckled eggs.

Comment: 1.5 days= 8 hens, 8 eggs, 180 eggs/8 hrs= 22.5, 22.5x1.5 days= 33.75 days

Comment: Where did the eighth speckled egg-layer come from?

Comment: Ugh I'm not sure... I'm confused

Comment: The way I read this one more solid colored hen would give Farmer John $42$ hens.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the question states that if Farmer John had 42 hens, exactly one-third or 14 of those hens would be speckled; since the "missing" solid-coloured hen is not speckled, he *has* 14 speckled hens. 7 of these speckled hens lay speckled eggs, and John needs 132 (11 dozen) speckled eggs.

*Each hen and a half lays an egg and a half in a day and a half.* Therefore, among the speckled hens that lay speckled eggs:

- one hen lays one egg in a day and a half
- seven hens lay seven eggs in a day and a half
- seven hens lay 132 eggs in $\frac32\times\frac{132}7=\frac{198}7=28\frac27$ days.

Therefore Farmer John needs 29 whole days – a lunar month – to collect 11 dozen speckled eggs for sale.